# HTML/CSS Table Padding

Tags: html, css

I'm having a stupid issue using a table, I hardly ever use tables and I'm not sure why the first image has a huge space after it. I tried setting a width, using "-margin" & Padding. I cant find anything to reduce the size.

```
<tr class="tblpadding">
    <td>Character:</td>
    <td class="tdchar"><img src="http://www.xronn.co.uk/pokearena/assets/img/charcter/2.gif"></td>
    <td><img src="http://www.xronn.co.uk/pokearena/assets/img/charcter/2.gif"></td>
    <td><img src="http://www.xronn.co.uk/pokearena/assets/img/charcter/2.gif"></td>
</tr>
```

Best to see the fiddle to show the issue - http://jsfiddle.net/uh6j4/1/

Answer (score 3):

Because the column cell has larger width because of the `input type text` boxes, just add `colspan` to that cell

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/uh6j4/2/)

> Also, I just saw that you've inconsistent table cells in your
>   [example](http://jsfiddle.net/uh6j4/5/), so make sure you fix them according to your requirement.

---

But as far as the explanation goes, you need to use `colspan` on the column which will contain those images.

---

Also I would like to point this out, it's invalid to use `form` element nested as a `tr` direct child, you should use that inside a `td`, always validate your markup [here](http://validator.w3.org/) before you put your websites live... but as far as the idea goes, the signup form you are trying to build can be designed without tables..

Comment: Thanks! got it now appreciate it!

Comment: @user2598957 You welcome :) also when you are designing, keep the table borders on, just for debugging purposes, once done, you can simply turn them off

Answer (score 0):

actually, you should not be using table for creating a layout in the first place.
use div's instead.

to give the organized look that you have here, what you need to do is very simple use `min-width` on the labels for uniformity.

I've created the same look that your table have , using div's only.
if its the same, why bother? because my layout have a flexibility that yours dont have.

take a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/avrahamcool/uh6j4/7/